# Magellan Sticky Nav Colors

Tags: zurb-foundation, magellan

I just created as Magellan nav bar. I've managed to change the background colour and the font in the bar, but I'm wondering how I go about changing the "highlight" colour? At the moment, the default colour is a dark blue greeny colour.

Sorry if this is a really simple question, but I can't seem to find anything in the css....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your css

```
 .sub-nav dd.active a{
   background:#000000
}
```